# iptables Explicit Allow Policy

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, iptables, firewall

I am attempting to setup an Explicit Allow policy on my 20.04 Ubuntu web server. By running the following:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

Also added rules for ssh, http and https. Resulting in the following rule set:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Everything works as expected. However, when attempting to install certbot via snap, or clone a github repo. The connections are blocked. Verified by temporarily allowing all INPUT:

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

My question is, how do I go about determining what INPUT rules to create to support those actions? Or any other actions in the future?

I recognize I likely need the port #, but I am just unsure how to determine what that is. Or is it as simple as allowing all INPUT from that source (i.e., https://api.snapcract.io, https://github.com)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to allow for packets that are in response to any outgoing session started by you. This rule is needed:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -s $UNIVERSE -d $EXTIP -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Where: $EXTIF is your interface name; $UNIVERSE is 0.0.0.0/0 (or just leave it out); $EXTIP is your IP address (which you could leave out also).

To help determine what additional INPUT rules might be needed for proper operation of your server add a logging rule as your last INPUT chain rule before control passes through to your default DROP policy.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT DROP:" --log-level info
```

Be careful, as it might generate a great many log entries. By default the log entries will be in `/var/log/syslog` and `/var/log/kern.log`

Additionally, you do not have a local interface ACCEPT rule (unless that is the rule you list without interfaces, use `sudo iptables -xvnL`). You need one (before the above):

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much Doug. An exemplary answer if I've ever seen one!

Comment: I apologize. There is a loopback rule. Just not listed.